# Issue when trying to configure new symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I tried going to `http://localhost/Symfony/web/config` and then I clicked on "configure your symfony application" and then I am getting the following error:

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

Any idea what and how I should debug this? I am testing this on OS X Mountain Lion, apache2, and PHP 5.4.6

In my logs I am seeing the following:

```
[Tue Aug 28 00:59:29 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico
[Tue Aug 28 00:59:51 2012] [notice] child pid 27878 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 00:59:52 2012] [notice] child pid 27877 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 00:59:52 2012] [notice] child pid 27875 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Tue Aug 28 01:00:10 2012] [notice] child pid 27879 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Tue Aug 28 01:00:14 2012] [notice] child pid 27882 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 01:00:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico
[Tue Aug 28 01:00:23 2012] [notice] child pid 27883 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Tue Aug 28 01:00:24 2012] [notice] child pid 27884 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 01:00:26 2012] [notice] child pid 27885 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 01:01:09 2012] [notice] child pid 27889 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 01:01:09 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico
[Tue Aug 28 01:01:15 2012] [notice] child pid 27892 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 01:01:16 2012] [notice] child pid 27893 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Aug 28 01:01:20 2012] [notice] child pid 27894 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Comment: What OS/web server/version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @halfer I added some more details above

Comment: Are you using the OS X Apache, or one of your own installing? Can you run `php -v` without errors? Can you run a simple PHP application without errors?

Comment: I guess you're using PHP 5.4.6 with APC 3.1.12 ?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're looking for `http://localhost/Symfony/web/config.php` not `http://localhost/Symfony/web/config`.

It's in the docs. Check it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Comment: that file isn't the issue, was just a typo on my end

Comment: Sorry then. Is this just happening with Symfony?